# Convert given simple php to codeigniter controller and model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I  need to convert this simple php code to codeigniter model and controller .
inside while loop when fetching data $row indexing should be comes through foreach loop($columns).

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dt";

$columns[0] = 'id';
$columns[1] = 'first_name';
$columns[2] = 'last_name';
$columns[3] = 'position';
$columns[4] = 'office';
$columns[5] = 'salary';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$where_clause = "";
$where_clause_array = [];
foreach($_REQUEST['columns'] as $key=>$column) {
    if($column['search']['value'] != '') {
        $where_clause_array[] = $columns[$column['data']]." LIKE "."'".$column['search']['value']."%'";
    }
}
if(sizeof($where_clause_array) > 0) {
    $where_clause = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where_clause_array);
}

$order_by = " ORDER BY ".$columns[$_REQUEST['order'][0]['column']]." ".$_REQUEST['order'][0]['dir'];
$limit = " LIMIT ".$_REQUEST['start'].", ".$_REQUEST['length'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users".$where_clause.$order_by.$limit;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sqlTotal = $sql = "SELECT * FROM users".$where_clause.$order_by;
$resultTotal = $conn->query($sqlTotal);

$finalResult = [];
$finalResult['draw'] = $_REQUEST['draw'];
$finalResult['recordsTotal'] = $resultTotal->num_rows;
$finalResult['recordsFiltered'] = $resultTotal->num_rows;

$i=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $finalResult['data'][$i][] = $row["id"];
        $finalResult['data'][$i][] = $row["first_name"];
        $finalResult['data'][$i][] = $row["last_name"];
        $finalResult['data'][$i][] = $row["position"];
        $finalResult['data'][$i][] = $row["office"];
        $finalResult['data'][$i][] = $row["salary"];
        $i++;
    }
} else {
    $finalResult['data'] = [];
}

echo json_encode($finalResult);

$conn->close();?>
```

I  need to convert this simple php code to codeigniter model and controller .
inside while loop when fetching data $row indexing should be comes through foreach loop($columns).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1**

First thing first, DB credentials goes to application->config->database.php

**Step-2**

Controller

```
 class controllerName extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('your_model');
    }

    public function index(){
      $data['columns'][0]='id';
      $data['columns'][1]='first_name';
      $data['columns'][2]='last_name';
      $data['columns'][3]='position';
      $data['columns'][4]='salary';

      $result=json_encode($this->your_model->getResults($data));
      print_r($result);
    }
 }
```

**Step-3**

Model

```
  class Your_model extends CI_Model {

     public function getResults($data)
     {
       $where_clause = "";
       $where_clause_array = [];
       foreach($_REQUEST['columns'] as $key=>$column) {
        if($column['search']['value'] != '') {
        $where_clause_array[] = $columns[$column['data']]." LIKE "."'".$column['search']['value']."%'";
         }
        }
       if(sizeof($where_clause_array) > 0) {
        $where_clause = " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where_clause_array);
       }

       $order_by = " ORDER BY ".$columns[$_REQUEST['order'][0]['column']]." ".$_REQUEST['order'][0]['dir'];
       $limit = " LIMIT ".$_REQUEST['start'].", ".$_REQUEST['length'];
       }

       $result=$this->db->query('SELECT * from users'$where_clause.$order_by.$limit)->result_array();
       return $result;

      }
```

Comment: Okay that's great @Malik Mudassar's

Comment: Can u try this code on ur side with datatable jquery

Comment: Because i tried but not working

Comment: I just gave you an idea of how to convert it , you can dig deeper to fix result and result total arrays. you can also use count() function to get number of items in record set